# How to bind to Datacontext of selected TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, datacontext

I have a `TreeView` like so:

```
<controls:TreeView x:Name="treeView"/>
```

I try to bind the `Datacontext` of a different control to the `Datacontext` of the selected `TreeViewItem`. How would I go about that?

I tried:

```
<controls:DetailView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

And:

```
<controls:DetailView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Datacontext}"/>
```

Comment: well u should use the search Option...Look for DataTemplate

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem}"` should work.

Comment: @Clemens But I dont want to bind a TreeViewItem, does it directly bind to the datacontext?

Comment: I you've bound the TreeView correctly, SelectedItem does not return a TreeViewItem, but the item in the selected TreeViewItem's DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! Write that up as an answer and I accept it.